# Redeploying Office to a single client after manual uninstall

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, deployment, microsoft-office

One of our client PC's recently got random crash issues with MS Word. I manually uninstalled Office 2003 locally on the client, ran "gpupdate /force /boot" and expected the client to reinstall Office after rebooting.

It didn't.

I've ran gpupdate a couple of times, but nothing seems to take effect. The only thing in eventlog of interest is the regular info that group policy software settings has been enabled.

Any ideas why it won't reinstall by it self? Does Group Policy contain some kind of magic log where it keeps track of wich clients it has installed?

Edit: The redeploy function in Group Policy is out of the question, as it would reinstall Office on all our computers on the next reboot.

Edit2: RSOP (both cmd and mmc) shows Office 2003 software package as deployed.

Edit3: Tried moving the computer to a different OU with slightly different software packages (but with the same Office 2003 policy). The other software installed at boot-up, but still no Office.

Comment: I gave up and reinstalled the computer. Case closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to me also, I manually uninstall a GPO package and there's no way I got it back, I noticed that there is a registry key that holds the GPO packages deployed.

- Open regedit and browse HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\AppMgmt
- Look in the subkeys for the product you want to redeploy and remove that key.
- gpupdate /force

and the next time you reboot you will have the installation happening.

I haven't found a better way, it's a big problem for me, because users can uninstall the application "accidentally" and I haven't found a way around this.... amazing..

Comment: Thanks for this, I've updated your answer to be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have sufficient access to the AD where you could just move the computer to a new OU and apply a specific GPO to do the reinstall?  That would avoid reinstalling all systems.  It should be fairly quick as well.

BTW, did you run RSOP.MSC to see if there was anything there in the way of an explanation?

Comment: Hi. I'm the main administrator, so I have access to everything. The problem with creating a new OU is that I also have to create a new group policy object, with the customizations (etc). It's too much hassle and work IMHO.

I ran RSOP.MSC and the commandline RSOP, and both shows the Office software package without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up and reinstalled the computer. Case closed.

*Edit: See the accepted solution.*

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.

Comment: @jscott lazy boy :) I've already accepted an answer, this one is left here for historical reasons..

Comment: Many apologies, the new `/review` doesn't display all the answers.